# Line Chart using array

Tags: highcharts

How to use the below data to create a line chart using Highcharts?
I have tried adding my logics but not getting the expected result.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-simple

```js
data= {
  "Tue Oct 01 2019": 3,
  "Tue Oct 02 2019": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using this piece of code:

```
const dataObj = {
  "Tue Oct 01 2019": 3,
  "Tue Oct 02 2019": 1
};

let key,
    data = [];

for (key in dataObj) {
    data.push([+new Date(key), dataObj[key]]);
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [{
    data: data
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k6Luy8qb/1/